# Hive Table Creation for Dynamic Schemas

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, hive, bson, hiveql

We are investigating whether Hive will allow us to run some SQL-like queries on 
mongo style dynamic schema as a precursor to our map-reduce jobs.

The data comes in the form of several TiB of BSON files; each of the files contains
JSON "samples".  An example sample is given as such:

```
{
    "_id" : "SomeGUID",
    "SomeScanner" : 
    {
        "B64LR" : 22,
        "Version" : 192565886128245
        },
        "Parser" : 
        {
            "Size" : 73728,
            "Headers" : 
            [
                {
                    "VAddr" : 4096,
                    "VSize" : 7924.                  
. . . etc. . . .
```

As a dynamic schema, only a few of the fields are guaranteed to exist.

We would like to be able to run a query against an input set that may be something
like

```
SomeScanner.Parser.Headers.VSize > 9000
```

Having looked up the table-mapping, I'm not sure whether this is do-able with Hive . . . how would one map a column that may or may not be there . . . not to mention that there are about 2k-3k query-able values in a typical sample.

Hence, my questions to the Experts:

- Can Hive build a dynamic schema from the data it encounters?
- How can one go about building a Hive table with ~3k columns?
- Is there a better way?

Appreciated, as always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK--with much ado, I can now answer my own questions.

- Can Hive build a dynamic schema from the data it encounters?
  A:  No. However, an excellent tool for this exists. q.v., inf.
- How can one go about building a Hive table w/~3K columns
  A:  Ibidem
- Is there a better way?
  A:  Not that I found; but, with some help, it isn't too difficult.

First, a shout out to Michael Peterson  at http://thornydev.blogspot.com/2013/07/querying-json-records-via-hive.html, whose blog post served as the toe-hold to figure all of this out.

Definitely check it out if you're starting out w/Hive.

Now, Hive cannot natively import a JSON document and deduce a schema from it . . . however, Michael Peterson has developed tool that does:  https://github.com/midpeter444/hive-json-schema

Some caveats with it:
* Empty arrays and structs are not handled, so remove (or populate) them.  Otherwise, things like `{ "something" : {} }` or  `{"somethingelse": []}` will throw errors.

- If any field has the name "function", it will have to be re-named prior to executing the CREATE TABLE statement. E.g., the following code would throw an error:  1{ "someThing": { "thisIsOK": "true", "function": "thatThrowsAnError" } }`

Presumably, this is because `"function"` is an Hive keyword.

- And, with dynamic schema in general, I have not found a way to handle a nested leading underscore name even if the schema is valid:  `{ "somethings": { "_someVal": "123", "otherVal": "456" } }` will fail.
- For the common MongoDB "ID" field, this is map-able with the following addition:  `with serdeproperties("mapping.id" = "_id")`, which appears to be similar to a macro-substitution.

Serialization/De-Serialization for JSON can be achieved with https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde by adding the following:  `ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'`

*N.B.*, the JsonSerDe JAR must have been added to .hiverc or "add jar"'d into Hive to be used.
Thus, the schema:

```
CREATE TABLE samplesJSON 
    ( id string,
       . . . rest of huge schema . . . . )
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
WITH serdeproperties("mapping.id" = "_id");
```

The JSON data can be loaded into the table with a command along the lines of:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/tmp/samples.json' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE samplesJSON;
```

Finally, queries are actually intuitive straight-forward.  Using the above example from the original question:

```
hive> select id, somescanner.parser.headers.vaddr from samplesjson;
OK
id    vaddr
119   [4096,53248,57344]
```